# Disord bot status not working in discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm currently programming a bot for discord, but my code isn't working and I'm not sure why.

I've tried using a variety of different solutions and have searched up many times but none of those answers work.

I'm sure the issue is probably very simple but I was wondering if anyone could help?

Here is my code:

```js
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('bot is online')
    client.user.setStatus('available')
    client.user.setPresence({
        game: {
            name: 'with ducks',
            type: 'PLAYING',
            url: 'https://discord.com'
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `game` to `activity` as shown in the [Discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/PresenceData). You can also set the status in the `.setPresence()` function instead of using the `.setStatus()` function.

```js
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('bot is online');

    client.user.setPresence({
        status: 'available',
        activity: {
            name: 'with ducks',
            type: 'PLAYING',
            url: 'https://discord.com'
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you so much. I understand my mistake now
thank you also for replying so quickly, I really appreciate it.